# Find patches with data in raster and then extract those patches

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I have a single band raster file as drawn in the labeled image attached.
[image]

The size of raster is around 4k pixel in each x and y axis. Large part of this raster is empty. Only in small portions of the raster contains data as labeled. Is there any efficient way I can extract rectangular patches around the data portions of the large `tif` raster file?

Any pythonic way using `gdal` or `rasterio` or some other package.

**What I have done so far:**
I have followed from `sklearn.feature_extraction.image`way to extract 2D patches where there is data as follows.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches_2d
im = imageio.imread(largeFilePath) # reading the large image
x, y = np.nonzero(im) # taking xy locations with non zero values

# determining xleft, xright, yleft and yright of the non zero area in 
raster 
xl,xr = x.min(),x.max() 
yl,yr = y.min(),y.max() 

#Extraing the non zero area from my original raster
only_desired_area = im[xl:xr+1, yl:yr+1]

# my desired window to extract 
window_shape = (480, 480)

# 2D Ptaches extraction
B = extract_patches_2d(only_desired_area, window_shape, max_patches=100)
```

**Issue:**
This doesn't have georeference information because I haven't used `gdal` or `rasterio`

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please don't delete and repost closed questions - You need to edit your existing question to take account of comments and then it will be reopened